# Как перевернуть H2 чтобы ширина и высота поменялись значениями

Tags: html, css, html5, веб-программирование

Существует блок H2 который находится в блоке(flex) с карточкой. Нужно перевернуть заголовок на -90 градусов. rotate(-90deg) выдает нужный визульный результат но ширина высота заголовка остаются такими же а не меняются местами как надо :

```
HTML
<style>
   .flex{
     display:flex;
   }
   h2{
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
   }
</style>
<div class='flex'>
    <h2>Пример<h2>
    <div class='dontcare'>
      Lorem
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

h2 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
}

.text-vertical {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: scale(-1, -1); 
}
```

```html
<div class='flex'>
  <h2>Пример</h2>
  <div class='dontcare'>Lorem</div>
</div>

<div class='flex'>
  <h2 class="text-vertical">Пример</h2>
  <div class='dontcare'>Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо